# "request" or "request for"

Tags: verbs

> You should request a higher rate for the days you've worked last weekend.
> You should request for a higher rate for the days you've worked last
> weekend.

I have no doubt that the first sentence correct. What about the second? It looks like a mix-up between "request" and "ask for".
If it's also correct, is there any difference in meaning? When should which be used?

This question is about the verb only. If "request" is a noun ("a request for more money") "for" is obviously necessary.

Comment: The second sentence is incorrect, since _request_ as a verb means _ask for_.

Comment: The noun _request_ takes a _for_ to introduce the object of the request, but the verb _request_ just takes an object; no preposition required: _He requested a double Scotch/his request for a double Scotch_.

Comment: Both are incorrect for combining the present perfect *have worked* with *last weekend*.

Answer (score -1):

If I check Wikipedia there's written,

> Request may refer to:
> a question, a request for information
> or a petition, a formal document demanding something that is submitted to an authority

Now when we are saying,"You should request a higher rate for the days you've worked last weekend" it means a kind of petition or something which I deserve, like I deserve to get a higher rate.

And, "You should request for a higher rate for the days you've worked last weekend" may mean sympathetically a bit, that it would've been helpful to get a higher rate.

However, both are correct to me.

Comment: The noun petition can replace the noun request. But if you petition for something, you are using petition as a verb: ask for something formally, in writing.